# Embeded Web Page Within Activity After Click Second Link

Tags: android, webview, android-activity, android-webview

I open some web pages in my activity, when i click link from my application it opens link within itself. But when page load if I click some link in web page it opens in system's default browser. How I can prevent it?

for example:

- If I click http://www.nytimes.com/ from my application it opens within app
- then nytimes loads and I click to http://www.nytimes.com/pages/world/index.html in nytimes's menu, now opens in Chrome Web Browser

This is my code part in `onCreate()`

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://"+URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a WebViewClient to your WebView and then override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method as follow.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // do what you want

        // return true if the host application wants to leave the current 
        // WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.
        return true;
    }
});
```